# Use scanf for unsigned octal/hexidecimal int in C

Tags: c, scanf

In C, scanf uses `%d` for decimal int, `%o` for octal int, `%x` for hexadecimal int, `%i` for all three, and `%u` for unsigned int. Any of these letters can be prepended with `l` or `h` for long, or short.

But is there a way to scan an unsigned octal int, or unsigned hexadecimal int? I tried things like `%ux`, `%xu`, `%ui`, etc. but they do not seem to work. K&R and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) do not mention anything either. And simply using `%u` sees "010" as "10", instead of octal for 8.

Comment: `%o` and `%x` scan and print unsigned numbers. `But is there a way to scan an unsigned octal int, or unsigned hexadecimal int?` - yes, `%o` for `unsigned int` printed in octal, and `%x` for `unsigned int` printed in hex.